# Java: JVM memory consumption

Tags: java

I am playing around with Java, parameter -Xms and class Runtime.

I see that JVM allocates about 15% of the memory that is available - regardless how much it is.

```
Runtime rt Runtime.getRuntime ();
long total = rt.totalMemory ()
long free = rt.freeMemory ();
```

That is the case if I start my programm with paramter

```
-Xms4000m
```

as well as with

```
-Xms90m
```

I see the difference of Xms in the result of totalMemory.

I understand the strategy of allocating more from the beginning to avoid expensive reallocation.

But I do not know if that is in place here AND how I can meter the real memory-consumption of my program.

Comment: gc logging is the easiest way

Comment: Did you mean to specify `-Xmx` instead?

Comment: no, Xms is the parameter that affects totalMemory

Answer (score 1):

If your're using the Oracle JVM, you can use the command line tool *jmap* or the GUI tool *jvisualvm* to measure the heap consumption of your Java program.

Answer (score 1):

Get the PID of the application and you can use top command in the below way to print out the statistics.

top -b | grep PID

You can see how the memory is utilized over time.